# An important lemma involving diverging sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $ \{a_i \}_{i \geq 0} $ be a sequence of **positive** reals such that $\sum_{i \geq 0} a_i := S$ exists and is finite. Define $S_i = \sum_{ j \geq i} a_i$. Prove that $\sum_{i \geq 0} \frac{a_i}{S_i}$ is divergent.

I tried a bunch of things like writing $b_i = \log \frac{a_i}{S_i}$ and working with that and using $-(1-x) \geq \log x$ or $e^x \geq 1+x$ but couldn't go very much further. A hint would be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand the first answer with the approximation by log